# Getting error "TypeError: this.$state is undefined" using Vuex on VueJS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

The goal is auth the user from Firebase and store the state using Vuex, when app is opened I use the state to know if user is logged in, and use it to more actions.
I need get a state to populate a variable on `data()` method on **App.vue** file, but it apparentely not getting the correct reference. When the page is loaded the follow error occurs:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: this.$state is undefined"
found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

and

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "isLoggedIn" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view v-if="isLoggedIn"></router-view>
    <login v-else />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import login from "@/views/Login";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    login
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoggedIn: this.$state.getters.user != null
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: null,
    status: null,
    error: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, payload) {
      this.user = payload
    },

    removeUser(state) {
      this.user = null
    },

    setStatus(state, payload) {
      this.status = payload
    },

    setError(state, payload) {
      this.error = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setUserAction({ commit }, payload) {
      commit('setUser', payload)
      commit('setStatus', 'success')
      commit('setError', null)
    }

  },
  modules: {
  },
  getters: {
    status(state) {
      return state.status
    },

    user(state) {
      return state.user
    },

    error(state) {
      return state.error
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you mean `this.$store` instead of `this.$state`?

Comment: Yes @skirtle, it worked. But the new page is not loaded on <router-view>

Comment: If you want it to update when `state.user` changes you should use a `computed` property instead of a `data` property.

Comment: I changed to `computed: {
    checkIsLoggedIn() {
      console.log(this.$store.getters.user);
      return this.$store.getters.user != null;
    }
  }` and `<router-view v-if="checkIsLoggedIn"></router-view>`. But not works

Comment: @Augusto by "not works", what is the error now? it should have changed from "type error this state is undefined"

Comment: the reactive not occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already have something like this to initialize vue and vuex

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App' // src/App.vue
import store from './store' // store/index.js

Vue.use(store)

new Vue({ store, render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app') // notice the "store" attribute here
```

So in component, it should be available in `this.$store.state`

And also, as @skirtle has pointed out, use computed if you want it to reactive with vuex

```
computed: {
  isLoggedIn () {
     return  this.$store.getters.user != null // remove .state
     // or you can use the state directly
     // return  this.$store.state.user != null
  }
}
```

In vuex, you should make change to state with a mutation. I see you already have setUser

```
setUser(state, payload) {
  state.user = payload // change this.user to state.user
},
```

you can then change the state in component with `this.$store.commit('setUser', this.user)`

And I see you have made an action `setUserAction` to do 3 commits, so you can just call it in component with `this.$store.dispatch('setUserAction', this.user)`

Comment: the `isLoggedIn` method is not called after status changed from `Login` page.

Comment: on the login component I changed from `this.$store.dispatch("setUserAction", user);` to `this.$store.state.user = user` and the code worked fine =)

Comment: @Augusto are you positive that vuex state user is changed from null?
I can't think of any other problem.

Comment: @Augusto no, don't change the state directly, you should use dispatch or commit

Comment: You can edit your answer to make the correct way to use Vuex set and get?

Comment: @Augusto seems like I found the mistake, see the comment in mutation setUser, should be `state.user` instead `this.user`

Comment: So, to set value I need use `this.$store.dispatch('setUserAction', user)` and should be work fine?

Comment: @Augusto yes, to change the state you can dispatch an action with commit, or you can just do commit directly with `this.$store.commit('mutation_name', payload)`, but don't change the state without mutation.